# jquery-mobile: label+input+label in some lines

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a form that have some inputs that I want to show in line, but it breaks line before width is so small. This is the code:

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain' id='TempLimits'>
<label for='Tmin' style='display-inline;width:50px'> Min.:</label>
<input type='text' name='Tmin' id='Tmin' value='0' style='display:inline;width:50px' />
<label for='Tmin' style='display-inline;width:50px'> ºC</label>
<br>
<label for='Tmax' style='display-inline;width:50px'>Max.:</label>
<input type='text' name='Tmax' id='Tmax' value='60' style='display:inline;width:50px' />
<label for='Tmax' style='display-inline;width:50px'> ºC</label>
```

And this is the images that show what I want to keep and what is the problem (i can't publish directly by reputation):

[In line labels](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/1690/forminline.png)
[Not in line labels](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8765/formnoinline.png)

Furthermore, there is any way to have labels aligned to center/bottom of input instead of top of input?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append the css-style `float: left` to the elements, which automatically go to the next line.

I think this should work for the first line:

`<label for='Tmin' style='width:50px'> Min.:</label>
<input type='text' name='Tmin' id='Tmin' value='0' style='float: left; width:50px' />
<label for='Tmin' style='float: left; width:50px'> ºC</label>`

Comment: I remove my last comment because was wrong. It works for first line, but I don't know how to make new line to force the second line to make the same function

Comment: Now all is working fine, simply using paragraphs  `<div data-role='fieldcontain' id='TempLimits'>
 <p><label for='Tmin' style='float: left;width:50px'>Min.:</label>
 <input type='text' name='Tmin' id='Tmin' value='0' style='float: left;width:50px' />
 <label for='Tmin' style='float: left;width:50px'> ºC</label></p>
 <p><label for='Tmax' style='float: left;width:50px'>Max.:</label>
 <input type='text' name='Tmax' id='Tmax' value='60' style='float: left;width:50px' />
 <label for='Tmax' style='float: left;width:50px'> ºC</label></p>
</div>` Thanks a lot

Comment: before using paragraphs, I would recommend to use <span> instead :)

Comment: I will take in care,actually I just change the float:left by display:inline-block that have the same result but I prefer that. With using display:inline-block, I can't use span because it doesn't break line between two blocks...